# MATLAB: Using get in cellfun for a cell array of objects

Tags: matlab, object, get, cell-array

I've been stuck with this for a while and I couldn't find something similar asked previously (or I have failed in doing so)

My situation is fairly simple: I have a cell array of objects. They are all the same object and I have a get function for this kind of object which is: get (obj, attr), where obj is the object in question and attr is a integer from 1-6. Depending on the number the get function returns the corresponding attribute.

I would like to obtain all of my "position" attributes from all my objects which are in the corresponding cell array (this would be attr = 2). I know that cellfun performs a function on all cells, but the question is, how do I use my get function here for all my objects, taking into account that the function is  get (obj, attr) ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The first argument to `cellfun` would be an anonymous function that embeds the `attr` parameter: `@(x)get(x,attr)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, by using `get` as a custom function you are shadowing the built-in [`get` function](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/get.html) - this is bad practise!

With this in mind, and to avoid confusion with the built-in `get` function which has similar syntax, I'm going to use `getattr` as a stand-in for your custom function which accpets an object and an integer 1 to 6.

```
pos = cellfun( @(obj) getattr( obj, 2 ), myCellOfObjects, 'uni', 0 );
```

By specifying `'uni', 0`, the output doesn't have to be scalar and will be put into a cell array. This is useful when, for example, you have a multi-element array for your position.

This is equivalent to the following loop:

```
pos = cell( numel(myCellOfObjects), 1 );
for ii = 1:numel(pos)
    pos{ii} = getattr( myCellOfObjects{ii}, 2 );
end
```

If ever in doubt about `cellfun` or `arrayfun`, just write a loop first - they are essentially the same but more concise.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick to this some are unaware of: you can pass multiple arguments to cellfun like this:

```
cellfun(@(obj,attr) get(obj,attr), {obj1,obj2},{attr1,attr2},'uni',0)
```

if you want to get one attribute of the cellarray (instead of providing an attribute for every object in the cellarray), then you can simply use this

```
cellfun(@(x) getattr(x,attr),obj,'uni',0)
```

put into anonymous function for convenience:

```
get_attr = @(obj,attr) cellfun(@(x) getattr(x,attr),obj,'uni',0)
%use:
get_attr(obj_in_cellarray,'myattribute') 
%returns cell array of object attributes
```

I haven't run any of these functions since you didn't provide any example data / code. Please test and feedback.